# Convert ISO string to specific date format

Tags: javascript

I need to display date in a certain format in application. I have input of '2009-04-01' as string and I want this format April 1, 2009 using Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `Date` object:

```
const date = new Date('2009-04-01');
```

Format the `Date` using `toLocaleString`:

```
date.toLocaleString('en-us', { month: 'long', day: 'numeric', year: 'numeric' });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new Date object and then use that to format the output:

```
d = new Date("2009-04-01")
```